# TYPO3: Indexed search and crawler relation

Tags: content-management-system, web-crawler, typo3

I've done several sites with TYPO3 indexed_search.  However I feel I still do not understand the nature of the relation between indexed_search and crawler.  For instance, according to some authors to index tt_news I just need a generic crawler configuration and an indexed_search configuration for tt_news; but for other authors of tutorials and such I should create a crawler configuration for tt_news.

It is not clear to me what the relation is between crawler and indexed_search.  How do they match?  Shouldn't it be sufficient a root crawler configuration that when it finds an indexed_search configuration just runs it?  Or does the URLs need to be generated by both?  I've managed to create an index with just one crawler root configuration but I run the indexing through my own shell script that calls cli_dispatch.phpsh.

Are indexed_search and crawler redundant in terms of functionality (generation of URLs)?

Any clues are welcome.

Bests,

B.

Answer (score 1):

Indexed_search can work without a crawler by indexing pages that are visited by visitors. The obvious disadvantage is that pages that aren't visited won't be indexed and thus won't show up in search results. If you have several frontend user groups configured then the chances that a page is visited are even lower.

The crawler can solve this by visiting each page. Furthermore it can visit pages as if it were member of (a combination of) FE user groups. This way it can help build the index of an entire website for all kinds of users.

Most of the details are explained in a [tutorial](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html) by Xavier Perseguers. It's written for an older version but I guess that most of it is still valid.
(It's been a while since I last used indexed_search, but at that time the tutorial helped a lot).

Comment: Hi.  Thank you very much for your answer.  I actually have used several times that tutorial.  It is very much a recipe type of tutorial.  I would like a better understanding of the inners of indexed search.  In the latest versions the have been using Fluid and some bugs have been appearing (from my point of view).  I also would like to understand why there is a duplicity of functionality in crawler and indexed search.

Comment: Jigal, maybe you know the answer to this:  why is it that the crawler_im script does not process indexed search hooks and the crawler script does it?  I know this for a fact since I am reviewing the source code and to me it has absolutely no logic.  Do you have an insight on this?  Bests.